# Perl: Separate array value by certain variable string

Tags: arrays, perl

Need advice on how to separate array data into different column base on certain string.  Like example below base on "EXIT" to split data & print into different column. Thank.

Example:

## Input

John

Eva

Felix

Exit

a

b

c

Exit

1

2

3

## output

John        a             1

Eve         b             2

Felix      c             3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the elements, store them into an array of arrays, resetting the index of the outer array on each `Exit`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my @arr = qw(John Eva Felix Exit a b c Exit 1 2 3);

my @out;
my $index = 0;

for (@arr) {
    if ('Exit' eq $_) {
        $index = 0;

    } else {
        push @{ $out[$index++] }, $_;
    }
}

say join ' ', @$_ for @out;
```

If the input lines aren't of the same length, you can assign to the particular element in the array:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my @arr = qw(John Eva Felix Exit a b c d e f Exit 1 2 3 4);

my @out;
my $outer = 0;
my $inner = 0;

for (@arr) {
    if ('Exit' eq $_) {
        $outer = 0;
        ++$inner;

    } else {
        $out[$outer++][$inner] = $_;
    }
}

say join "\t", map $_ // q(), @$_ for @out;
```

Comment: thank for the prompt respones, Choroba.
In case source data from array display horizontally as given example, can i use the same method as above?

Comment: @wwkeen: I don't understand. Arrays don't display, but you can display them in any way you like.

Comment: Sorry my bad, i mess up with other bug problem with this one. Ignore me.Your code did help me a lot.

Comment: In case i have array that don't have equivalent of same variables, anything that need to add-in for above code.
Example: my @arr = qw(John Eva Felix Exit a b c d e f Exit 1 2 3 4);

But need to arrange in each column separate by name, character & number.

Comment: @wwkeen: I don't understand what output you expect.

Comment: output something look like:

John a 1
Eva  b 2
Felix c 3
  d 4
  e

Comment: I can't actually put down my expected output inside this comment box, 
had some limitation in term of spacing & tab.

In high level, it will be arrange name ( John Eva & Felix) in first column; characters ( a b c d e f) in 2nd column, while number (1 2 3 4) in 3rd column horizontally.